# Laravel - pluck with specified keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, pluck

I have a line of code similar to the following:

```
Sport::pluck('id', 'name)
```

I am dealing with frontend JavaScript that expects a list in this format:

```
var list = [
 { text: 'Football', value: 1 },
 { text: 'Basketball', value: 2 },
 { text: 'Volleyball', value: 3 }
 ...
]
```

I am trying to figure out how I can somehow transform the `id` and `name` values that I pluck from my model to a format similar to the Javascript `list`.

If that's unclear, I am looking to end up with an associative array that contains two keys: `text` and `value`, where `text` represents the `name` field on my model, and where `value` represents the `id` of the model - I hope this makes sense.

How would I approach this?

I initially tried something like this (without checking the documentation)

```
Sport::pluck(["id" => "value", "name" => "text]);
```

But that isn't how you do it, which is quite clear now. I've also tried some map-related snippet, which I cannot seem to Ctrl-z to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

Another method is to use `map->only()`:

```
Sport::all()->map->only('id', 'name');
```

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `pluck` is not what you intend to do,

Please have a look at below examples,

```
Sport::selectRaw("id as value, name as text")->pluck("text","value");
// ['1' => 'Football', '2'=>'BasketBall','3'=>'Volleyball',...]
```

Syntax

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('name', 'product_id');
// ['prod-100' => 'Desk', 'prod-200' => 'Chair']
```

Please see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck).

Your output is possible using simple code.

```
Sport::selectRaw('id as value, name as text')->get();
```

Comment: You're right. Your suggestion is a lot simpler and somehow a refreshing reminder that good ol' queries still do the trick. I guess I was too in the zone with Eloquent to think about giving the columns aliases in a regular query. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use map.(https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map)

```
$mapped = Sport::all()->map(function($item, $index) {
 return [
   "id" => $item["id"],
   "name" => $item["text"]
 ];
});
```

This is the easiest way. Actually Laravel offers a better way for it. You can use api resources to transform your data from eloquent for the frontend:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 1):

Try with `toArray` function:

```
Sport::pluck('id', 'name)->toArray();
```

Then you can return your result with `json_encode` php function;

Comment: Hey, thanks for contributing. I struggle to understand how this achieves the renaming of the keys.